# How to get meaning of flags by integer

Tags: compilers

Assuming I have a syscall to `open`.

`man 2 open` gives me info, that it requires 2 or 3 parameters

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

So, my code runs and In my registers I have

```
$rdi = 0x00007fffffffdb40 → "/etc/init.d/",
$rsi = 0x0000000000000241,
$rdx = 0x00000000000001c9
```

How and which flags is it using during the call? How will the dir (or file) be opened?

1. I am looking at the man page. The possible flags are mentioned, but not their bit/value/integer being set by `|`'ing the flags together in source code.
2. I continue at the man page and see above the header files, which define the constants. In this case I'd need to `#include <sys/types.h> <sys/stat.h> <fcntl.h>`. However, in this files, I cannot find bits or integers, which `sum` or `|` up to the given flags (`$rsi = 0x241`, `577` in decimal, `1001000001` in binary) I cannot see any pattern.

Question: Do I oversee something? Do I need to look somewhere else? Where are those bits described?

Comment: You cant. Flags are defined with preprocessor `#define`. So compiler will replace that definition with integer. Only enumerations and structures can shows values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flags are constants drawn from here:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/include/uapi/asm-generic/fcntl.h

They *can* change but very rarely.

---

Applying this we can see that

`0x241 == O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC`

Comment: For me it is not obvious to get from `O_CREAT 00000100` | `O_WRONLY 00000001` | `O_TRUNC 00001000` to 0x241 ? What number-system do they use in this header file? Do you maybe have a reference on how to read those numbers?

Comment: literals prefixed with `0` are octals, so `0100` is 64 or 0x40. `01000` is 0x200, `1` is 1, so we're 0x40 + 0x200 + 1 = 0x241.

Comment: thanks, makes sense now. For everyone else might read this, here is additional info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326133/why-fcntl-flag-values-are-defined-in-octal-format-how-this-function-works-fo